# How to display message inline

Tags: html, css

I have an image which shows a plus sign and next to the image it displays a little message. Code is below:

```
<table id="plus" align="center">
<tr>
<th>
<input type="image" src="Images/plussign.jpg" name="plussign" width="30" height="30" id="plusimage"><span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

The issue I have is that the message is not really displayed inline next to the image. The image is 30 pixels high but the message is displayed about from bottom 10 pixels high. How can I get the message next to the image to display inline with the image properly.

Below is css:

```
#plusimage{
    clear:right;    
}        

#plussignmsg{
    font-size:10px; 
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Could I suggest a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo?

Comment: What do you mean by`properly`, should it be at the top, in the middle at the bottom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#plusimage{
    float:left;   
}        

#plussignmsg{
    font-size:10px; 
    display: block; float:left;
}
```

Lately I found display the container as table,and contents as table-cell also works.

Comment: That's if you want to see the image and text display inline side by side.You must set the text to be block element,so two blocks can float.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `float` the image

```
#plusimage{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#plusimage{
    display:inline;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this. I have added css class for align image to vertical middle.

<style type="text/css">
    #plusimage
    {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
   </style>
   <table id="plus" style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="image" src="Images/add_user.png" name="plussign" id="plusimage"><span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look up Previous Questions)</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```